# How to get the id of both the draggable and the droppable inside callback function

Tags: jquery

I would like to drag and drop between the two  divs. 
For this i am using the following javascript which works fine

```
var PortletDraggable = function () {

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            if (!jQuery().sortable) {
                return;
            }

            $("#sortable_portlets").sortable({
                connectWith: ".portlet",
                items: ".portlet", 
                opacity: 0.8,
                handle : '.portlet-title',
                coneHelperSize: true,
                placeholder: 'portlet-sortable-placeholder',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                tolerance: "pointer",
                helper: "clone",
                tolerance: "pointer",
                forcePlaceholderSize: !0,
                helper: "clone",
                cancel: ".portlet-sortable-empty, .portlet-fullscreen", // cancel dragging if portlet is in fullscreen mode
                revert: 250, // animation in milliseconds
                update: function(b, c) {
                    if (c.item.prev().hasClass("portlet-sortable-empty")) {
                        c.item.prev().before(c.item);
                    }   
                    alert('update called');
                   console.log('c'+c.item.index());
                }
            });
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    PortletDraggable.init();
});
```

And Whenever there is a drag drop happens there is a callback function by name  update which gets fired

Is it possible to get the id of both the draggable and the droppable elements

https://jsfiddle.net/33keyjxx/14/

For example if i move **cricket** to fourth position the current position of cricket and its id also .

Comment: Isn't the draggable and the droppable element the same thing in this case? What elements are you expecting to get

Comment: For example if i move cricket to fourth position the current position of cricket and its id also .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/33keyjxx/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your sortable options:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
   console.log(ui.helper[0].id);
   console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
}
```

Documentation [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start)

Use `start` when dragging and `stop` when dropping

Comment: why is this giving  VM142:98 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null inside  stop: function(event, ui) {
   console.log(ui.helper[0].id);
   console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
}

Comment: under start its fine ,but under stop there is a problem with  console.log(ui.helper[0].id);

Comment: get used to use the console to debug, so `console.log(ui.helper)` first, it will return an object, so inspect the object what's in there

Comment: when you do `console.log(ui)` you see that the helper is null because there isnt one, so you have item as well so go for `console.log(ui.item.context.id);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log('c'+c.item.attr("id"));
console.log('b'+b.item.attr("id"));
```

Comment: i am getting VM142:92 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined